# Align pictures top center, bottom right and bottom left

Tags: java, android-linearlayout, android

I'm trying to align 3 pictures in a LinearLayout so that one is centered at the top, another is at the bottom aligned to the left side and the last is at the bottom aligned to the right side. Pretty much like a pyramid. How could I do this? Can you provide an example?

i.e

```
 X
X X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any way to control the spacing between the top and the bottom images? When I either do it this way or with a RelativeLayout, the spacing between the top image and the bottom two images is the whole screen.

Comment: No.. for as requirement i have set it to bottom. Otherwise if you change height of last second layout to wrap content then if display correctly with no space.

Comment: @Piyush Gupta: so many Layouts... why?! you should aim to **flatten** your hierarchy as musch as you can, for memory and performance optimization (mostly true for older devices, but also newer ones will enjoy a flat structure).

Answer (score 1):

You need a **RelativeLayout**, not a LinearLayout.

Image A must specify the attribute

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true".
```

Image B must specify the attributes

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

and

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true".
```

Image C must specify the attributes

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

and

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Comment: @Zack: Thank you for correction. Right, I always forget layout_... I was going by memory, while working on my project. ;)

Comment: No problem. This answer is also correct, but uses RelativeLayout. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It will be more flexible if you do it in **RelativeLayout** but if you want to do it in **LinearLayout** here is the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```